# If you can see sharp

Tags: riddle

> Started with a wink, a handshake.
>
> (if you know what I mean)
>
> Ideas in plain or in secret, all is within!
>
> Secret? Well, it depends, study until.
>
> Animals perform, machines obey, people create.
>
> Create! The classics... do you even see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Is this a reference to

> code (specifically the C# Programming Language?) Thanks to @nikki for some return inspiration!! :D

Started with a wink, a handshake.

> This was started by Microsoft a while back. Per @nikki, a wink and a handshake could be a secret code between a fraternity/sorority/group of people, etc. (wink wink nudge nudge, know what I mean)

Ideas in plain or in secret, all is within!

> Everything can be coded by the language, whether a plain idea or a secret one. This could be either computer code or secret code.

Secret? Well, it depends, study until.

> You need to study to learn C# or other kinds of code. In order to decode secret messages, you need to study the decryption techniques.

Animals perform, machines obey, people create.

> There are animal classes in C sharp; another animal which performs could be GNU, an operating system which runs code, machines obey the code which people create.

Create! The classics... do you even see?

> *See*, as in the classic *C* per the OP.

Comment: The original word I had in mind is in your 5th spoiler block. Yours is a bit more specific, but you got the reference right and a nice answer :-)

Comment: Is my answer more correct now @villasv?

Comment: You went in the right direction, but not quite there yet. I guess its on me for not giving enough specificity... sorry! Still trying to learn ;-)

Comment: Title says literally "see sharp"(c#)

Comment: Thanks @YoutRied! :D If you look at the edit history this was my first guess, to which I was told I didn’t quite have it.

Comment: Yes! Now you nailed basically everything. rot13(Gur ynfg bar jnf vaqrrq whfg P, abg P#, orpnhfr P vf gur pynffvpny bar). Great teamwork, I upvoted both but will accept this one ;)

Answer (score 4):

Is the answer

> code?

Started with a wink, a handshake.
(if you know what I mean)

> A wink is the code for a secret handshake

Ideas in plain or in secret, all is within!

> Plain:Coding like programming, Secret: En-coding messages?

Secret? Well, it depends, study until.

> Study and de-code the message?

Animals perform, machines obey, people create.

> Machines obey code that people write, not sure about animals...

Create! The classics... do you even see?

> C programming language?

Gained a bit of inspiration from @El-Guest

Comment: All your explanations but the first one  and the animals, think other meanings of the same word ;)